# Needlessly closed a question?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

This question was closed as off topic.
[LightDM login screen configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957011/lightdm-login-screen-configuration)

Now LightDM is used with ubuntu and Ubuntu Mate. The DM, greeter, and setting package are available in ubuntu.

The OP had said Debian Stretch, so as it states at the bottom of the close message, I edited the post to fit ubuntu rules: replacing "Debian Stretch" with  "LightDM Greeter" since the question is about the greeter. Thus, making it pertain to ubuntu as well.

However, it was closed anyway. Although the OP wasn't using ubuntu, why deprive ubuntu users of the information they may want to customize their login screen?

Edit:
A lot of responses seem to be hung on two words that are irrelevant to the question. the OP could have just as easily said "I'm using 16.04 and want to make the Lighdm greeter look like the unity greeter" and his pictures would have been the same.  Zana gives the best reason to do anything to the post "there are a lot of answers here about configuring the greeter".

@Zana -- LightDM greeter and Unity greeter are not equivalent. if they were, there wouldn't be two seperte packages in the repo.

For the rest, LightDM and lightDM greeter are available in most linux distros. so how can asking how to customize it be a Debian question??

Comment: "I'm using Debian, but I would like to make this thing look like Ubuntu's equivalent thing" - that's a question *helpful to people using Debian*, not to people using Ubuntu. It belongs on U&L. We have other questions about customising the login screen

Comment: if you allow "how to change to LightDM" as pertaining to ubuntu, then "how to customize the greeter?" also pertains to ubuntu.

Comment: What's your motivation here? We can *distort* the question so that it fits here, but it's clearly a much better fit and much more likely to help people on U&L. Why are you so determined to keep it here?

Comment: I have locked this question to stop the flood of useless, meaningless comments that are now encroaching upon the "Be Nice" rule.  This lock will remain for a week.  If you want to continue to discuss this civilly, move to chat.  Otherwise, drop the issue and cease the arguing and bickering that was taking place here.

Answer (score 6):

#### I think we should *not* reopen that question but could migrate it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

This question is about Debian, not Ubuntu. When a user posts a question about Debian and it *also* applies to Ubuntu--but they are not also using Ubuntu--we still generally consider that off-topic. In this case, the question doesn't even appear to apply to Ubuntu.

The *problem* being solved here seems extremely unlikely to occur on Ubuntu. After all, **Ubuntu already looks like Ubuntu!** As [Zanna says](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17295/needlessly-closed-a-question#comment35743_17295), that the OP is running Debian and *not* Ubuntu is a pretty important part of the question, and it is Debian users--not Ubuntu users--that the question stands to help.

I've seen a login screen like the OP's all the time on Debian, and never on Ubuntu. Even if the problem *does* also happen on Ubuntu, we usually only generalize off-topic questions for the purposes of reopening them when they are particularly useful to Ubuntu users. In practice this typically means that there are already helpful answers that clearly provide value--*often* by having multiple upvotes--and that there is some reason to avoid migrating the question, such as it being *(a)* especially useful on Ubuntu or *(b)* too old to migrate.

Right now, with the edits that have been applied to it to, the question doesn't even make any sense:

> I'm using LightDM Greeter and my LoginScreen looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdjql.png). I wonder if it is possible to make it look like the [ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDczO.png) version? ***...***

If readers are supposed to assume this could be Ubuntu, how are they supposed to interpret the text "make it look like the ubuntu version?" As currently written, if the question were reopened as not being *off-topic*, it would probably be swiftly re-closed as *unclear*.

If your concern is that the question should be *(a)* answered or *(b)* not lost, then I think the solution is to improve the question a bit--restoring the information about Debian, inlining the images into the post, copyediting--and to ask a moderator to migrate the question to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). (The improvements should be made prior to migration, because only high-quality material ought to be migrated.)

Comment: yes, my concern is both a) and b). as this question is about how to modify the appearance of the LightDM greeter. The immage posted is the default look for the LightDM greeter. So in essence, the questin is "How do I make the LightDM greeter look like the Unity greeter?" PS - ubuntu is returning to Gnome Desktop, yes? will it also revert to LightDM Greeter?

Comment: **My big concern is this**... as written by the author, the question was clearly off topic... they had Debian Stretch. The **proper** action would have been VTC... **NOT** edit the question, for the author, trying to make it fit into the rules and make it on-topic. What happens with other posters that claim to use Elementary OS, or SUSE, or Fedora, or some other flavor or Linux... we're now going to edit all of these questions to fit into a Ubuntu framework?